# Pass in JFrame to change brightness?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, brightness

I am trying to make a popup over my JFrame in Swing. I have made it so that the popup will be layered over the old JFrame and disable the old one by passing in the JFrame and then .disable(). However, i am also trying to make the frame behind darken to show that it is disabled.

I found this:
[stackoverflow - Change brightness of JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368208/change-brightness-of-jframe)

But how do i use it to lower the brightness of the JFrame that i have as a parameter just before i disable it? Something like darken(frame) and it lowers it using the function darken(JFrame frame). Thanks!

Comment: That's not how you disable the JFrame. You do this by using a modal JDialog. As for dimming the JFrame, show us ***your*** code, preferably a [small, working, minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and tell us how it's not working. One way to consider is to use the JRootPane's glass pane.

Comment: My "popup" is a JDialog that i customized so that uses an image for the background, and the .disabled part works even though it says deprecated. Sorry if its bad practice i'm new to programming

Comment: Make the dialog modal (see my example below), and it would be best to avoid using deprecated methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I'm going to make my comment an answer:

- To show a window over another window, and disable the lower window, make the upper window a ***modal*** JDialog, and pass the lower window in as its parent.
- One way to dim a top-level window is to get its glass pane, set it visible, and draw a semi-opaque grey color over it.

---

Here's my test of concept code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DimView {
   protected static final Color GP_COLOR = new Color(0, 0, 0, 30);

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame("DimView");
      final JPanel glassPanel = new JPanel() {
         protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(GP_COLOR);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
         };
      };
      glassPanel.setOpaque(false);
      frame.setGlassPane(glassPanel);
      JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
      mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
      mainPanel.setBackground(Color.pink);
      mainPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Push Me") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            glassPanel.setVisible(true);

            JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Dialog",
                  ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            dialog.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(200, 200)));
            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
            dialog.setVisible(true);

            glassPanel.setVisible(false);
         }
      }));

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a JLabel with a semi-opaque image as its icon and set it as its GlassPane. Works like a charm

Comment: @user3285692: great -- glad you've got it working! It worked for me with a JPanel, just setting it visible or not. Please see code above for example.